# why i can't update user's picture by user_save()

Tags: users, media

i wrote the program belowed

```
$fields=array('name'=>'test user','picture'=>$fid);
```

`$account=user_save($account, $fields);`

i really changed the user name but i can't change the picture field in the users table

what could the problem be?

by the way, i also use db_update. The situation is the same

the code is blowed

```
db_update('users')
->condition('uid',$account->uid)
->fields(array('picture'=>$file->fid))
->execute();
```

still not work
I hope somebody can help me,Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hybrydauth module does somethink like this

```
$file = new stdClass();
  $file->uid      = $account->uid;
  $file->status   = 0; // mark the file as temporary
  $file->filename = basename($tmp_photo_realpath);
  $file->uri      = $tmp_photo;
  $file->filemime = $info['mime_type'];
  $file->filesize = $info['file_size'];

  // The file should be an image
  $errors = array();
  $errors += file_validate_is_image($file);
  $errors += file_validate_image_resolution($file, variable_get('user_picture_dimensions', '85x85'));
  $errors += file_validate_size($file, variable_get('user_picture_file_size', '30') * 1024);

  // Make sure file extension is a valid image
  if (!in_array(strtolower($info['extension']), array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
    $errors[] = ' invalid image file extension.';
  }

  if (count($errors)) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Profile Image Import:') . ' ' . $errors[0], 'warning');
    // Clean up (set fid to avoid error messages)
    $file->fid = 0; file_delete($file);
  }
  else {
    // We'll need a valid file id on the file object; file_save() will give us one
    $file = file_save($file);
    // Update user account (fid is not empty, status is temporary -- image
    // will be moved to proper directory and assigned to the user)
    $fields['picture'] = $file;
    $account = user_save($account, $fields);
```

Comment: thx for providing this code, i actually just used this code and doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
 $file = file_load($fid);
 $file->status = 0;
 $edit = array ('picture' => $file);
 $u = user_save($account,$edit);
```

Comment: $file->status = 0; should be $file->status = 1;

Answer (score 0):

This is done in fboauth module

```
  // Update the user record.
  $picture_file->uid = $account->uid;
  $picture_file = file_save($picture_file);
  file_usage_add($picture_file, 'user', 'user', $account->uid);
  db_update('users')
    ->fields(array(
    'picture' => $picture_file->fid,
    ))
    ->condition('uid', $account->uid)
    ->execute();
```

you can use this code you just have to load file `$picture_file` first using [file_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_load/7)